# Now What is the best way to render HTML from the API in a React component?

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to render an html response from an API in React.
API response includes pure html Tags...
Currently what is the best way to convert html tags to the correct JSX element ?
Is it correct to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

HTML Response:

```
Wayland Parrott <span class="searchmatch">Flowers</span> Jr. (November 26, 1939 – October 11, 1988) was an American actor, comedian and puppeteer. <span class="searchmatch">Flowers</span> was best known for the comedy
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by converting HTML tags to JSX. Do you want to parse the HTML string? Or do you just want to render the HTML string? I am assuming you mean rendering HTML as string in React and, I am afraid `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is the **only** way to do it.

Comment: I mean render the HTML string in React

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.